# multipart data getting corrupted ,size is 0 in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipartform-data

Here is my code I am posting PDF file using multipart Data:

I am using iOS 10

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"abc123defg321sdfdff";

        __block NSData   *filedata;
        NSString*str=[[attachData.fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]objectAtIndex:1];
        if([str caseInsensitiveCompare:@"jpg"]||[str caseInsensitiveCompare:@"png"]){
            [attachData loadOriginalImageWithCompletion:^(UIImage * _Nullable resultImage) {
                filedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resultImage, 0.9);

            }];
        }else{

            filedata      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:attachData.originalFileResource];
        }
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];




        //add params
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", @"data"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",requestJson]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];





        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",fileParams,attachData.fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        if([str caseInsensitiveCompare:@"jpg"]||[str caseInsensitiveCompare:@"png"]){

            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }else {

            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        }

        [body appendData:filedata];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // This is the final delimiter which ends the body in format "--%@--".
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSLog(@"httpbody:%@",body);

        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSURLResponse *response; NSError *error;

        NSData*responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                 error:nil];
```

When I check in DB file is there with same name but size is zero, no content.

Comment: no `"Content-Length"` in the header? that could be the reason...

Comment: it was working but suddenly stop working working,files getting corrupt at server end

Answer (score 0):

code for multipart upload

```
    var url_request  = URLRequest(url: URL(string: “tester/url”)!)
    url_request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
    url_request.timeoutInterval = 60
    url_request.httpMethod = "POST"`

    let boundary = “—————App——————“
    let form_data = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    url_request.setValue(form_data, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()


    /*--------------- test ---------------*/
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\”\(test_key)\r\n\r\n”)
    body.appendString(“\(test_obj)\r\n”)

    /*----------- Image --------------*/
    if (str_photo_val != nil)
    {
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"
        let defFileName = “test.jpg”
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(str_photo_val!, 1)

        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(str_photo_key)\"; filename=\"\(defFileName)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageData!)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
    }
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")

    url_request.httpBody = body as Data
    let postLength: String = "\(UInt(body.length))"
    url_request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url_request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                hideLoadingHUD(for_view: self.view)
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
            print("Result -> \(String(describing: jsonData))")

            let succed = jsonData?[APIKey.success.rawValue] as? Bool
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  hideLoadingHUD(for_view: self.view)
                    }
            }

    }
    catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                hideLoadingHUD(for_view: self.view)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Replace the image to pdf. pdf convert to NSData and after you upload the Data to parameter

Comment: pdf convert to NSData and after you upload the Data to parameter

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you point out any error or missing thing in my code and am not using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Content type change to `PDF format` and file name also used to `.pdf`

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.pdf\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:datadat]];
```

Try this code.